# How to get month in string type from Date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

This is my SQL query.

```
select orderDate from orders;
```

From this, I can get output like this

```
03-OCT-96
```

How can I get a Month (like 'OCT') from the orderDate?

Comment: what is you orderDate datatype? is it a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select substring(cast(orderDate as string), 4, 7) as month from orders
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the proper way to do this would be to first convert your date string to a bona fide date using `STR_TO_DATE`, then use `DATE_FORMAT` to extract out a month string in whatever format you want, e.g.

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('03-OCT-96', '%d-%b-%Y'), '%M')
-- October
```

Note that storing your dates as *text* in the format of `%d-%b-%Y` is generally bad practice.  Consider using a formal date column, to avoid the costly conversion with `STR_TO_DATE`.